# lambda i=i: not giving result for button in loop

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm new to coding and tkinter and after looking for solution to create button in a loop I ended on this solution:

```
while x <= 10:
    btn = Button(text=x).grid(row=1, column=1)
    window.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x=x: print(x))
```

But this solution return:

```
<ButtonPress event state=Mod1 num=1 x=57 y=12>
```

and not the value of x.

What would be a solution for that?

Comment: What is the meaning of`x`?

Comment: What is the meaning of`x`? Did you mean to have `i` like you have in the question title?

Comment: `window.bind` takes a callback that will always be given an event as its argument. The *parameter* `x` is bound to that event; the variable `x` you use to set the default argument is unrelated and unused, since the callback will never be called without an event. I believe what you want is `lambda e: print(e.x)` instead.

Comment: I fixed the mistake with the i-->x.

Adding event in front of lambda did not fix it since now the value of x used is the last (in this case10)

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a function to an event, that function will be called with a parameter. This parameter is an object representing the event.

In your case you're binding to an anonymous function that accepts one argument named `x`. Thus, when the function is called, even though you've initialized `x` to an integer, `x` will be set to this event object.

The solution is that your `lambda` needs to accept this event along with the parameter `x` so that `x` doesn't get overwritten.

```
window.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, x=x: print(x))
```

However, the code snippet you provided doesn't define `x` (ie: `x` isn't a loop variable and you don't do `x=...` anywhere) so I'm not sure if that's quite right. If you want `x` to be the loop variable then it needs to be `x=i`:

```
window.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, x=i: print(x))
```